# Does anyone know how Adobe Color's 'Extract Theme' function works to produce a colour palette?

Tags: c++, image, colors, k-means, quantization

I am trying to implement a system for extracting colour palettes from an image in C++. I basically want something exactly like the way [Adobe Color's 'Extract Theme'](https://color.adobe.com/create/image) function works.

I have tried implementing a version of median cut, but the averaging of the colours ultimately produces an unpleasing selection of final colours (though I may have implemented it wrong, I'm not sure).

I have tried k-means clustering ([using this header library](https://github.com/genbattle/dkm)) but it doesn't seem to pick up a good selection of colours.

For example, here are the five colours that Adobe Color picks out of an example image: [Adobe Color version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsIVT.jpg)

And here are the five colours selected by the k-means approach: [K-Means version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3c7YO.png)

Does anyone have any idea what's going on for the colour selection in the Adobe Color version? I'm trying to implement this inside Unreal Engine using C++, if that makes any difference.

Thanks.

Comment: you should also include how you define the similarity/distance between colors. a [mcve] would be even better.

Comment: Did you look at *"Color Thief"*?

Comment: I believe I was using the Euclidean distance to define colour distance. I’ll work on trying to get an example prepared.
I did find Color Thief, and it seems great, but there’s no easy way to run JS from inside Unreal (have had a quick look today but kept hitting walls) and it’s slightly beyond me to convert JS to C++, though perhaps that’s what it will come to. 
I just thought there would be an easy, portable way to do this, but I’ve been trying all day with no luck…